# Why can I fill buffer without sigfault?

Tags: c, memory, buffer, overflow

Here is a main "problem". Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buf[10];
    strcpy(buf,argv[1]);

    printf("%s",buf);

    return 0;
 }
```

I'm trying overflow stack like that:

```
gcc main.c -o runMe
./runMe "$(printf '%.sA' {1..15})"
```

But output is clear. No overflow. So ... what the heck???

Comment: I get a segfault doing that.. so I would guess it depends on your OS memory atm ? 
What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the buffer overflows? If you can be more specific about the compiler you are using, your target platform, and what you expect to achieve (i.e. hijack the return address), the community would be more willing to help.

Comment: I didn't cause an accident when I ran a red light yesterday. Must have been unlucky.

Comment: Don't tag spam. This is C and not C++.